# Is there a way to convert a unicode escape sequence within the Logstash pipeline so that the actual emoji icon is show within Elastic?

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch, rubygems, logstash, emoji

I am sending messages from Kafka in to Logstash and then through to Elastic, some of the messages contain emojis, these emojis are converted to Unicode escape characters when being stored in Kafka e.g.

---> is converted to \ud83d\ude0a

I want Logstash to convert \ud83d\ude0a back in to  when processing my message so that the actual emoji icon is shown within elastic, instead of the unicode version. I have researched different ways to do this such as using ruby gems (emoji and logstash-filter-emoji), however there are no examples on how these ruby gems can be used within Logstash.

- https://rubygems.org/gems/unicode-emoji
- https://rubygems.org/gems/logstash-filter-emoji/versions/1.0.2

Is there a way achieve this within the Logstash pipeline ?

Comment: I'm not sure that logstash-filter-emoji does what you want: `Map syslog severity to emoji ⚠️`